# SAM Build Fails when using SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, aws-lambda

I am trying to use the sqlalchemy library in a Lambda I want to upload. This uses a AWS Lambda project created using the AWS toolkit in Pycharm. The sqlalchemy library is used only to insert pandas tables into mysql (tables have 300+ columns with more to be added in the future, so explicitly defining column names is not an option). Note that the library is included within the requirements.txt file.
The lambda runs fine when running on my local machine using the "Build function inside a container" parameter inside the run configurations. I believe this parameter is the equivalent to using the command:

`sam build --use-container`

However, the configuration for remotely deploying the lambda does not include the parameter "Build function inside a container". As such I get the following error when I attempt the deploy my function remotely:

```
2019-04-17 13:23:07 Using SAM Template at /Users/davidpell/PycharmProjects/lambda/template.yaml
2019-04-17 13:23:07 Changing event name from creating-client-class.iot-data to creating-client-class.iot-data-plane
2019-04-17 13:23:07 Changing event name from before-call.apigateway to before-call.api-gateway
2019-04-17 13:23:07 Changing event name from request-created.machinelearning.Predict to request-created.machine-learning.Predict
2019-04-17 13:23:07 Changing event name from before-parameter-build.autoscaling.CreateLaunchConfiguration to before-parameter-build.auto-scaling.CreateLaunchConfiguration
2019-04-17 13:23:07 Changing event name from before-parameter-build.route53 to before-parameter-build.route-53
2019-04-17 13:23:07 Changing event name from request-created.cloudsearchdomain.Search to request-created.cloudsearch-domain.Search
2019-04-17 13:23:07 Changing event name from docs.*.autoscaling.CreateLaunchConfiguration.complete-section to docs.*.auto-scaling.CreateLaunchConfiguration.complete-section
2019-04-17 13:23:07 Changing event name from before-parameter-build.logs.CreateExportTask to before-parameter-build.cloudwatch-logs.CreateExportTask
2019-04-17 13:23:07 Changing event name from docs.*.logs.CreateExportTask.complete-section to docs.*.cloudwatch-logs.CreateExportTask.complete-section
2019-04-17 13:23:07 Changing event name from before-parameter-build.cloudsearchdomain.Search to before-parameter-build.cloudsearch-domain.Search
2019-04-17 13:23:07 Changing event name from docs.*.cloudsearchdomain.Search.complete-section to docs.*.cloudsearch-domain.Search.complete-section
2019-04-17 13:23:07 Changing event name from creating-client-class.iot-data to creating-client-class.iot-data-plane
2019-04-17 13:23:07 Changing event name from before-call.apigateway to before-call.api-gateway
2019-04-17 13:23:07 Changing event name from request-created.machinelearning.Predict to request-created.machine-learning.Predict
2019-04-17 13:23:07 Changing event name from before-parameter-build.autoscaling.CreateLaunchConfiguration to before-parameter-build.auto-scaling.CreateLaunchConfiguration
2019-04-17 13:23:07 Changing event name from before-parameter-build.route53 to before-parameter-build.route-53
2019-04-17 13:23:07 Changing event name from request-created.cloudsearchdomain.Search to request-created.cloudsearch-domain.Search
2019-04-17 13:23:07 Changing event name from docs.*.autoscaling.CreateLaunchConfiguration.complete-section to docs.*.auto-scaling.CreateLaunchConfiguration.complete-section
2019-04-17 13:23:07 Changing event name from before-parameter-build.logs.CreateExportTask to before-parameter-build.cloudwatch-logs.CreateExportTask
2019-04-17 13:23:07 Changing event name from docs.*.logs.CreateExportTask.complete-section to docs.*.cloudwatch-logs.CreateExportTask.complete-section
2019-04-17 13:23:07 Changing event name from before-parameter-build.cloudsearchdomain.Search to before-parameter-build.cloudsearch-domain.Search
2019-04-17 13:23:07 Changing event name from docs.*.cloudsearchdomain.Search.complete-section to docs.*.cloudsearch-domain.Search.complete-section
2019-04-17 13:23:07 'build' command is called
2019-04-17 13:23:07 No Parameters detected in the template
2019-04-17 13:23:07 2 resources found in the template
2019-04-17 13:23:07 Found Serverless function with name='HelloWorldFunction' and CodeUri='hello_world/'
2019-04-17 13:23:08 Building resource 'HelloWorldFunction'
2019-04-17 13:23:08 Loading workflow module 'aws_lambda_builders.workflows'
2019-04-17 13:23:08 Registering workflow 'PythonPipBuilder' with capability 'Capability(language='python', dependency_manager='pip', application_framework=None)'
2019-04-17 13:23:08 Registering workflow 'NodejsNpmBuilder' with capability 'Capability(language='nodejs', dependency_manager='npm', application_framework=None)'
2019-04-17 13:23:08 Registering workflow 'RubyBundlerBuilder' with capability 'Capability(language='ruby', dependency_manager='bundler', application_framework=None)'
2019-04-17 13:23:08 Registering workflow 'GoDepBuilder' with capability 'Capability(language='go', dependency_manager='dep', application_framework=None)'
2019-04-17 13:23:08 Registering workflow 'GoModulesBuilder' with capability 'Capability(language='go', dependency_manager='modules', application_framework=None)'
2019-04-17 13:23:08 Registering workflow 'JavaGradleWorkflow' with capability 'Capability(language='java', dependency_manager='gradle', application_framework=None)'
2019-04-17 13:23:08 Registering workflow 'JavaMavenWorkflow' with capability 'Capability(language='java', dependency_manager='maven', application_framework=None)'
2019-04-17 13:23:08 Registering workflow 'DotnetCliPackageBuilder' with capability 'Capability(language='dotnet', dependency_manager='cli-package', application_framework=None)'
2019-04-17 13:23:08 Found workflow 'PythonPipBuilder' to support capabilities 'Capability(language='python', dependency_manager='pip', application_framework=None)'
2019-04-17 13:23:08 Running workflow 'PythonPipBuilder'
2019-04-17 13:23:08 Running PythonPipBuilder:ResolveDependencies
2019-04-17 13:23:08 calling pip download -r /Users/davidpell/PycharmProjects/lambda/hello_world/requirements.txt --dest /var/folders/c4/jqqz7trx02l9w1qkbx8dzxvr0000gn/T/tmpgl5r1tqp
2019-04-17 13:23:13 Full dependency closure: {numpy==1.16.2(wheel), six==1.12.0(wheel), requests==2.21.0(wheel), pytz==2019.1(wheel), pymysql==0.9.3(wheel), urllib3==1.24.1(wheel), python-dateutil==2.8.0(wheel), setuptools==41.0.0(wheel), sqlalchemy==1.3.3(sdist), pip==19.0.3(wheel), idna==2.8(wheel), chardet==3.0.4(wheel), certifi==2019.3.9(wheel), pandas==0.24.2(wheel)}
2019-04-17 13:23:13 initial compatible: {six==1.12.0(wheel), requests==2.21.0(wheel), pytz==2019.1(wheel), pymysql==0.9.3(wheel), urllib3==1.24.1(wheel), python-dateutil==2.8.0(wheel), setuptools==41.0.0(wheel), pip==19.0.3(wheel), idna==2.8(wheel), chardet==3.0.4(wheel), certifi==2019.3.9(wheel)}
2019-04-17 13:23:13 initial incompatible: {numpy==1.16.2(wheel), pandas==0.24.2(wheel), sqlalchemy==1.3.3(sdist)}
2019-04-17 13:23:13 Downloading missing wheels: {sqlalchemy==1.3.3(sdist), numpy==1.16.2(wheel), pandas==0.24.2(wheel)}
2019-04-17 13:23:13 calling pip download --only-binary=:all: --no-deps --platform manylinux1_x86_64 --implementation cp --abi cp37m --dest /var/folders/c4/jqqz7trx02l9w1qkbx8dzxvr0000gn/T/tmpgl5r1tqp sqlalchemy==1.3.3
2019-04-17 13:23:14 calling pip download --only-binary=:all: --no-deps --platform manylinux1_x86_64 --implementation cp --abi cp37m --dest /var/folders/c4/jqqz7trx02l9w1qkbx8dzxvr0000gn/T/tmpgl5r1tqp numpy==1.16.2
2019-04-17 13:23:15 calling pip download --only-binary=:all: --no-deps --platform manylinux1_x86_64 --implementation cp --abi cp37m --dest /var/folders/c4/jqqz7trx02l9w1qkbx8dzxvr0000gn/T/tmpgl5r1tqp pandas==0.24.2
2019-04-17 13:23:16 compatible wheels after second download pass: {numpy==1.16.2(wheel), six==1.12.0(wheel), requests==2.21.0(wheel), pytz==2019.1(wheel), pymysql==0.9.3(wheel), urllib3==1.24.1(wheel), python-dateutil==2.8.0(wheel), setuptools==41.0.0(wheel), pip==19.0.3(wheel), idna==2.8(wheel), chardet==3.0.4(wheel), certifi==2019.3.9(wheel), pandas==0.24.2(wheel)}
2019-04-17 13:23:16 Build missing wheels from sdists (C compiling True): {sqlalchemy==1.3.3(sdist)}
2019-04-17 13:23:16 calling pip wheel --no-deps --wheel-dir /var/folders/c4/jqqz7trx02l9w1qkbx8dzxvr0000gn/T/tmpgl5r1tqp /var/folders/c4/jqqz7trx02l9w1qkbx8dzxvr0000gn/T/tmpgl5r1tqp/SQLAlchemy-1.3.3.tar.gz
2019-04-17 13:23:17 compatible after building wheels (no C compiling): {numpy==1.16.2(wheel), six==1.12.0(wheel), requests==2.21.0(wheel), pytz==2019.1(wheel), pymysql==0.9.3(wheel), urllib3==1.24.1(wheel), python-dateutil==2.8.0(wheel), setuptools==41.0.0(wheel), pip==19.0.3(wheel), idna==2.8(wheel), chardet==3.0.4(wheel), certifi==2019.3.9(wheel), pandas==0.24.2(wheel)}
2019-04-17 13:23:17 Build missing wheels from sdists (C compiling False): {sqlalchemy==1.3.3(sdist)}
2019-04-17 13:23:17 calling pip wheel --no-deps --wheel-dir /var/folders/c4/jqqz7trx02l9w1qkbx8dzxvr0000gn/T/tmpgl5r1tqp /var/folders/c4/jqqz7trx02l9w1qkbx8dzxvr0000gn/T/tmpgl5r1tqp/SQLAlchemy-1.3.3.tar.gz
2019-04-17 13:23:19 compatible after building wheels (C compiling): {numpy==1.16.2(wheel), six==1.12.0(wheel), requests==2.21.0(wheel), pytz==2019.1(wheel), pymysql==0.9.3(wheel), urllib3==1.24.1(wheel), python-dateutil==2.8.0(wheel), setuptools==41.0.0(wheel), pip==19.0.3(wheel), idna==2.8(wheel), chardet==3.0.4(wheel), certifi==2019.3.9(wheel), pandas==0.24.2(wheel)}
2019-04-17 13:23:19 Final compatible: {numpy==1.16.2(wheel), six==1.12.0(wheel), requests==2.21.0(wheel), pytz==2019.1(wheel), pymysql==0.9.3(wheel), urllib3==1.24.1(wheel), python-dateutil==2.8.0(wheel), setuptools==41.0.0(wheel), pip==19.0.3(wheel), idna==2.8(wheel), chardet==3.0.4(wheel), certifi==2019.3.9(wheel), pandas==0.24.2(wheel)}
2019-04-17 13:23:19 Final incompatible: {numpy==1.16.2(wheel), pandas==0.24.2(wheel)}
2019-04-17 13:23:19 Final missing wheels: {sqlalchemy==1.3.3(sdist)}
2019-04-17 13:23:20 PythonPipBuilder:ResolveDependencies failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/0.14.2/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aws_lambda_builders/workflows/python_pip/actions.py", line 39, in execute
    self.scratch_dir
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/0.14.2/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aws_lambda_builders/workflows/python_pip/packager.py", line 143, in build_dependencies
    requirements_path, artifacts_dir_path, scratch_dir_path)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/0.14.2/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aws_lambda_builders/workflows/python_pip/packager.py", line 212, in build_site_packages
    raise MissingDependencyError(packages_without_wheels)
aws_lambda_builders.workflows.python_pip.packager.MissingDependencyError: {sqlalchemy==1.3.3(sdist)}

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/0.14.2/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aws_lambda_builders/workflow.py", line 236, in run
    action.execute()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/aws-sam-cli/0.14.2/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aws_lambda_builders/workflows/python_pip/actions.py", line 42, in execute
    raise ActionFailedError(str(ex))
aws_lambda_builders.actions.ActionFailedError: {sqlalchemy==1.3.3(sdist)}
Build Failed
Error: PythonPipBuilder:ResolveDependencies - {sqlalchemy==1.3.3(sdist)}
```

The point of interest is

`calling pip download --only-binary=:all: --no-deps --platform manylinux1_x86_64 --implementation cp --abi cp37m --dest /var/folders/c4/jqqz7trx02l9w1qkbx8dzxvr0000gn/T/tmpgl5r1tqp sqlalchemy==1.3.3`

Removing the parameter `--only-binary=:all:` will allow this individual command to function, however I do not know whether this will help.

How can I build my lambda function that includes the sqlalchemy dependency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functionality within Pycharm exists. Right click on the root project folder as shown and select "Deploy Serverless Application".

[image]

Select whether to Create/Update a (CloudFormation) stack and then tick "Build function inside a container".

[image]